# Codeblocks c++ code compiles correctly, but console is downsizing itself and not showing the entire output

Tags: c++, console

Basically, whenever I run this program, the output window downsizes itself and I can only see the very end of it. Everything else is not shown even if I  resize the console myself, which means that while I can work on it, I can't see most results.

This is how it looks when it first opens

[image]

How it looks when I resize it

[image]

The code uses a lot of headers, so I'm leaving only the main in order to give you an idea of what I'm working with. Most things are in spanish as I'm natively a spanish speaker (and am required to code in spanish).

It's just a simple menu that allows you to input a specific amount of customers attending a veterinary.

I have no idea what the issue is, and because I'm working with people who are more knowledgeable in coding than me, I can't exactly debug it myself either.
I'm running on CodeBlocks 17.12, on Windows 10.

```
int main(){

    int opcion;
    bool salir = false;

    do{
        system("cls");
        cout << "\tBienvenido. Elija la opcion.\n\n";
        cout << "\t1)Registrar socio.\n";
        cout << "\t2)Agregar mascota.\n";
        cout << "\t3)Ingresar consulta.\n";
        cout << "\t4)Ver Socios ingresados.\n\n";
        cout << "\t0)Salir\n\n";
        cout << "\tOpcion: ";
        fflush( stdin );
        scanf("%d",&opcion);

        if (opcion==1){
                menuRegistrarSocio();
            }
        else if (opcion==2){
                cout << "Ingrese los datos de la mascota\n";
                system("PAUSE");
            }
        else if (opcion==3){
                    cout << "Ingrese los datos de la consulta\n";
                    system("PAUSE");
                }
        else if (opcion==4)
        {
            if(sistema.SOCIOS.size() == 0)
            {
                cout << "No hay socios creados" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                int cont = 1;
                map<char*, Socio*>::iterator i = sistema.SOCIOS.begin();
                while(i != sistema.SOCIOS.end())
                {
                    cout << cont << "- Nombre: " << i->second->getNombre() << " CI: " << i->second->getCi() << endl;
                    cont = cont + 1;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            system("PAUSE");
        }
        else if (opcion==0){
            salir = true;
        }
        else
            cout << " - Comando Incorrecto\n";

    }while (!salir);
    cout << "\n\n - BYE!\n";
}
```

All I need is for the output to show correctly, so I can keep coding.

**EDIT:**

I "fixed" it by quoting the "system("cls");" line. There's a few other system lines in the code, so I quoted them as well, because they were causing the same effect.

I don't really know what they do (never used this before), but now the program isn't completely unusable. The window will still downsize itself, but it shows everything this time, so I can resize it and use it as normal.

Comment: Went to edit your post to make the images visible and found they're the same thing. Suggestion step through the code in the debugger and see what's being called when the window shrinks.

Comment: edited the second image. Sorry about that. I'll try what you suggested tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I would try right clicking on the top bar of the console window where it says "D:####..." Then clicking Properties > Layout and changing the width and height.

Comment: Already tried that. Didn't work. Running again resizes the windows once more.